# Multiselect Combobox and tpl - Issue on marking selected entries in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, tooltip, extjs3

I have added quicktip(tooltip) for the combox by using tpl as below,

```
'<tpl for="."><div ext:qtip="{text}" class="x-combo-list-item">{text}</div></tpl>'
```

But after adding this, the combobox doesn't mark (in blue) the selected entries. ie, Before i am adding the tooltip, the selected entries can be seen as marked or selected (as blue color for me). But now its not working(the selected enitries are not seeing as selected).
Here is my code,

```
            {           
              name          : name,
              hideOnSelect  : false,
              triggerAction : 'all',
              mode          : 'local',
              width         : size,
              tpl           :'<tpl for="."><div ext:qtip="{text}" class="x-combo-list-item">{text}</div></tpl>',
              store         : new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
              id                : 0,
              fields            : ['value','text'],
              data          : data
              }),
              listWidth     : 400,
              valueField    : 'value',
              displayField  : 'text'
            }
```

[image] <---before
[image] <---after

Any help is must appreciated...Thank you.

Comment: can you elaborate the question ?

Comment: how can i change it for getting my requirement?can anyone reply?

Answer (score 1):

[displayTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) should work too:

```
{           
      name: name,
      hideOnSelect: false,
      triggerAction: 'all',
      mode: 'local',
      width: size,
      store: new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
          id: myCombo,
          fields: ['value','text'],
          data: data
      }),
      listWidth: 400,
      valueField: 'value',
      displayField: 'text',
      displayTpl: '<tpl for="."><div ext:qtip="{text}">{text}</div></tpl>'
}
```

**UPDATE**

Found the issue! You had to init the QuickTips first. The rest of your code was fine! Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/Nfwnn/)

```
Ext.QuickTips.init();
var cb = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    name: name,
    hideOnSelect: false,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    mode: 'local',
    width: 200,
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        id: "myCombo",
        fields: ['value', 'text'],
        data: [
            { value: 1, text: 'one'},
            { value: 2, text: 'two'},
            { value: 3, text: 'three'}
        ]
    }),
    listWidth: 250,
    valueField: 'value',
    displayField: 'text',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    tpl: '<tpl for="."><div ext:qtip="{text}" class="x-combo-list-item">{text}</div></tpl>'
});
```

Comment: Nope, sorry didn't see you were using Ext JS 3.4. I can only suggest an upgrade (but I know that this isn't always an option)

Comment: Did you know any other solution for the same in Ext JS 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this...

```
        {           
          name          : name,
          hideOnSelect  : false,
          triggerAction : 'all',
          mode          : 'local',
          width         : size,
          store         : new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
          id                : myCombo,
          fields            : ['value','text'],
          data          : data
          }),
          listWidth     : 400,
          valueField    : 'value',
          displayField  : 'text',
          listConfig: {
               getInnerTpl: function() {
                 return '<div data-qtip="{text}">{value}</div>';
               }
           }

        }
```

Comment: i have edited my answer... can you try that... and let me know

Comment: Everything is fine without quicktip. is that working in your side?